# Applying margin to a background image with fixed position

Tags: javascript, css

I have a background image that I want to cover my entire screen minus the header.  I also don't want my background image to scroll.  It should not move as the user scrolls over content.

For this reason I use the following to place my background:

```
    <div
      className={style.app}
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${HomePhoto})`,
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
      }}
    ></div>
```

I am attempting to add additional CSS properties to assume the proper height and width are used:

```
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
```

However the `margin-top` is not applied unless I remove `backgroundAttachment: "fixed"`.  Is there a way I can achieve both styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `backgroundPosition` property which allows you to move a background image around in its container: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```
<div
  className={style.app}
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${HomePhoto})`,
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    backgroundPosition: "100px 0", // or vh
  }}
></div>
```